# SimpleModal load external HTML page in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Is it possible to load an external HTML file into a variable and then use this variable to load the SimpleModal dialog? Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var externalPage $.get("Renderer.htm");

    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function(e) {
        $(externalPage).modal();

        return false;
    });
});
```

An alternative solution (that works) is loading the external HTML file in a hidden div and then use this to load the dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#simplemodal-content').hide(); // or hide in css
    $('#simplemodal-content').load("Renderer.htm");

    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function(e) {
        $('#simplemodal-content').modal();

        return false;
    });
});
```

However if I take this approach the css defined for the external page can interfere with my local page and thus change the layout, which is **not desired**.

If there's a 3rd solution that's better than these approaches, please share.

PS: sadly it also has to work perfectly in IE6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will need to use an iframe to accomplish this. Even if you are able to load the contents of the page into a variable once you display it on the page, its css and javascript will start affecting your page.

Something like this might work:

```
$('#iframeElement').attr('src','Renderer.html')
$('#iframeElement').modal()
```

Though you will probably not want to use the iframe directly as modal object, but I hope that this is enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Is a good base to get started. Seperates the css/js correctly.
I also added an alternative solution in a reply.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than loading the entire html file, load just one part of it.

```
$('#simplemodal-content').load('Renderer.htm body');
```

This will load the body only, excluding any CSS or scripts.

Comment: This way I won't have the css for the page when I place it in the modal dialog.

Comment: Oh, if you need the css then you should use the iframe as per Keare's answer. If you can't use iframe, then you should redo your css so that they're compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Keare is indeed useful to seperate the css/js from the external html so it doesn't interfere with the current page. It can also be used as a base for the modal dialog.

As an alternative I've also found this solution which uses an iframe in the modal dialog itself. In this case you might have a problem with scrollbars, which is already solved here: http://bit.ly/anbyf2

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function(e) {
    var src = "http://www.google.com";
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
        closeHTML: "",
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderColor: "#fff",
            height: 456,
            padding: 0,
            width: 834
        },
        overlayClose: true
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst rolling your own solution is great for learning, and may possibly be more efficient, there are plenty of jQuery plug-ins that do this (and have solved all the problems for you). Examples include:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ and http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 1):

A [comment](http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal-121-released/#comment-4868) on the SimpleModal site indicates that the following code should work:

```
$.get('page.html', function(data) { $.modal(data); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#iframeElement').load('Renderer.html');
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?